# How to initialize usb camera with location id in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

When I using two usb cameras named DinoLite, I find they have the same

> uniqueID *@"0xffffffffa1680710"*.

I don't know if it is the reason that only one of them can be recognized using `AVCaptureDevice` or `QTCaptureDevice`. they have the same 
only one difference between them is the location id, but I have no idea how to get camera device using location id.

please help me if you have any idea about ***how to initialize usb camera with location id***
thanks a lot

Comment: You should consult the manufacturer of the device.

Comment: @Raptor I did,they gave me a sdk but build for 32-bit i386 architecture,which is conflict with my project and other lib that using 64-bit x86_64 architecture.and they   don't have any plan to rebuild it.

Comment: library conflict is a complex matter. Sometimes it can be fixed by adjusting Build Phases, sometimes can't. At this moment there is insufficient information for me to help further.